# PHP String Function with non-English languages

Tags: php, utf-8

I was trying `range();` function with non-English language. It is not working.

```
$i =0
foreach(range('क', 'म') as $ab) {

    ++$i;

    $alphabets[$ab] = $i;

}
```

**Output**: à =1

It was Hindi (India) alphabets. It is only iterating only once (Output shows).

For this, I am not getting what to do!

So, if possible, please tell me what to do for this and what should I do first before thinking of working with non-English text with any PHP functions.

Comment: I have not got good answer or sometimes not tested myself after getting the answer, but I always come to Add Vote if it is of some help.

Comment: Well, this is a good thing too. :)

Comment: @SatyaPrakash See ans http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860270/php-string-function-with-non-english-languages/7860488#7860488

Comment: Please continue answering (spreading knowledge) for making the code work and Especially for this: "what should I do first before thinking of working with non-English text with any PHP functions." I will vote up for good answers.  There should be toggle button in PHP for this. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Short answer: it's not possible to use `range` like that.**

### Explanation

You are passing the string ['क'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/915/index.htm) as the start of the range and 'म' as the end. You are getting only one character back, and that character is `à`.

You are getting back `à` because your source file is encoded (saved) in UTF-8. One can tell this by the fact that `à` is code point `U+00E0`, while `0xE0` is also the first byte of the UTF-8 encoded form of 'क' (which is `0xE0 0xA4 0x95`). Sadly, PHP has no notion of encodings so it just takes the first *byte* it sees in the string and uses that as the "start" character.

You are getting back *only* `à` because the UTF-8 encoded form of 'म' also starts with `0xE0` (so PHP also thinks that the "end character" is `0xE0` or `à`).

### Solution

You can write `range` as a `for` loop yourself, as long as there is some function that returns the Unicode code point of an UTF-8 character (and one that does the reverse). So I googled and found these [here](http://ftzdomino.blogspot.com/2009/06/php-utf-8-chr-and-ord-equivalents.html):

```
// Returns the UTF-8 character with code point $intval
function unichr($intval) {
    return mb_convert_encoding(pack('n', $intval), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16BE');
}

// Returns the code point for a UTF-8 character
function uniord($u) {
    $k = mb_convert_encoding($u, 'UCS-2LE', 'UTF-8');
    $k1 = ord(substr($k, 0, 1));
    $k2 = ord(substr($k, 1, 1));
    return $k2 * 256 + $k1;
}
```

With the above, you can now write:

```
for($char = uniord('क'); $char <= uniord('म'); ++$char) {
    $alphabet[] = unichr($char);
}

print_r($alphabet);
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/PNOFA)**.

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful explanation. But how to make PHP function work with non-English Characters. If someone develop non-English sites then how they manage. What functions to forget with non-English text? How to know what will work or not? Thanks!

Comment: @SatyaPrakash: Basically, *nothing* will work for non-latin text unless it's part of the [mbstr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) or [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php) libraries. I also added a solution to the answer. Cheers!

Comment: I can't believe! It is working. It is not just showing numbers but Hindi character is also visible on your example code. I am not too much into PHP these days. So, thought I cannot get the answer even if I give many hrs myself on Google.

Answer (score 5):

The lazy solution would be to use [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) and [`range()`](http://php.net/range) only for the numeric ranges it was originally intended (that it works with ASCII is a bit silly anyway):

```
foreach (range(0x0915, 0x092E) as $char) {

    $char = html_entity_decode("&#$char;", ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
    $alphabets[$char] = ++$i;
}
```

Comment: +1, nice creative use of built-ins. It lacks the convenience of directly typing in the characters themselves, but OTOH it's all of three lines.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be translating and getting the range then translate back again.

```
$first = file_get_contents("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate?v=1.0&langpair=|en&q=क");
$second = file_get_contents("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate?v=1.0&langpair=|en&q=म"); //not real value
$jsonfirst = json_decode($first);
$jsonsecond = json_decode($second);
$f = $jsonfirst->responseData->translatedText;
$l = $jsonsecond->responseData->translatedText;
foreach(range($f, $l) as $ab) {


    echo $ab; 

}
```

Outputs

```
ABCDEFGHI
```

To translate back use an arraymap and a callback function that translates each of the English values back to hindi.

Comment: Hindi has more numbers of alphabets than English. I doubt it will work!

Comment: @SatyaPrakash Yeah, I considered that. Its not a 100 percent solution.