# Using Two Bytes Code Points in PHP

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8

I am working on this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860270/php-string-function-with-non-english-languages/)
written by Jon and Mario. It is working for Consonants in Hindi ( क -  ह) but not for vowels. One reason can be I am not able to feed two code points for letter (अः)

**I am trying these codes for range - अ - अः**

```
// Used decimal number. 
// Error - Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes
foreach (range(2309, 23092307) as $char) {

    $char = html_entity_decode("&#$char;", ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
    $alphabets[$char] = ++$i;
}

print_r($alphabets);
```

Tried this as well in for loop - 
"foreach (range(0x0905, '0x0905 0x0903') as $char)"

Also, this code:

```
// Output is Japanese/Chinese characters:
// 
function unichr($intval) {
    return mb_convert_encoding(pack('n', $intval), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16BE');
}

function uniord($u) {
    $k = mb_convert_encoding($u, 'UCS-2LE', 'UTF-8');
    $k1 = ord(substr($k, 0, 1));
    $k2 = ord(substr($k, 1, 1));
    return $k2 * 256 + $k1;
}

for($char = uniord('अ'); $char <= uniord('अः'); ++$char) {
    $alphabet[] = unichr($char);
}

print_r($alphabet);
```

It looks there was something with file encoding as well! As now it is returning this:
Array ( [0] => अ ) // only one line
I have tried with utf-8 and utf-16 document encoding.

Comment: I used this site for getting the code points:
http://www.branah.com/unicode-converter for अ - अः

Comment: Your first version is trying to create an array of 23 **MILLION** characters. For UTF-8, that can be up to 4 bytes per character, so in theory the array would take up somewhere north of 80 megabytes JUST for the character data, and then there's PHP overhead to consider... ouch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a big problem because there is not a single unicode code point (character) for `अः`. Instead it is the composition of the two characters `अ` (0x0905 or decimal 2309) and `ः` (0x0903 or decimal 2907).

So your first code sample loop end point of `23092307` is not valid. What you have done there is just concatenate the two code points together and treat them as a single value.

Your second code sample is only producing the single character because it is just using the first of the two code points in the `अः` which is the same code point as `अ`.

Maybe you could look at a nested loop. Have your outer loop over the base characters, and your inner loop add the composition characters. Something like:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach (range(0x0905, 0x0938) as $char)
{
    $txt = html_entity_decode("&#$char;", ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
    $alphabets[$txt] = ++$i;
    foreach ( range(0x0901, 0x0903) as $combine )
    {
        $txt = html_entity_decode("&#$char;", ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8")
             . html_entity_decode("&#$combine;", ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
        $alphabets[$txt] = ++$i;
    }
}
print_r($alphabets);
?>
```

Comment: Hmm! Looking little surprised that concat works and give character that I recognize as one. Can be accepted answer but looking for more.